# как из текстового файла извлечь строку с описанием при помощи python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется текстовый файл, в нём сформирована html-таблица, как вытащить 2 строки с неким описанием и поместить их в столбец в Excel, предварительно их обработав(в них присутствуют теги их нужно убрать)?

В текстовике множество таких строк, строки с описанием написаны кириллицей, остальные строки, либо кракозябры, либо просто теги.Не представляю как это реализовать, заранее спасибо всем тем кто откликнется.

[ссылка на файл](https://yadi.sk/d/fy2D5h-4iH4ODQ)

Нашёл вот такой код он удаляет все теги но этого недостаточно, нужно ещё зачистить то что было внутри тегов не считая столбцов `Prim` и `PrimRadio`:

```py
import re

f = open('test.txt', 'r').read()
raw_html = f.read()
f.close()

def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>|&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-f]{1,6});')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
    print(cleantext)

cleanhtml(raw_html)
```

Comment: Проведите несколько строк в качестве примера. А лучше весь файл где-то выложите

Comment: html-разметку можно распарсить специальными библиотеками (например, [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) из стандартной библиотеки, или [`beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)). Записать данные в xlsx файл можно с помощью библиотеки [`openpyxl`](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/)

Comment: либо поработать с регулярными выражениями. модуль re

Comment: А что конкретно вы хотите получить на выходе? Можно пример желаемого выхода?

Comment: нужно взять все содержимое столбца prim и primRadio, для наглядности пожалуйста посмотрите файл в формате html
на выходе хочется видеть только строки с описанием в отдельном excel файле, в идеале записывать их сразу в уже существующий excel

Comment: @Дмитрий, забивать гвозди микроскопом тоже можно, но малоэффективно и дорого.

Comment: @Namerek зато необычно и богато новым опытом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу то приблизительно вот так можно решить через bs4:

```py
# pip install bs4 openpyxl pandas
# Если не установлены
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from bs4.element import Tag

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('test.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as html:
        soup = Soup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

    rows = soup.find_all('tr')

    headers_row: Tag
    headers_row = rows[1]

    headers = {td.text.strip(): num for num, td in enumerate(headers_row.find_all('td'))}
    constructor = {h: [] for h in headers}

    for row in rows[2:]: # Вот здесь нужно уточнить структуру файла из которого читаем данные
    # Тоесть как там располагаются строки относительно друг друга
    # Тоесть больше строк нужно для понимания структуры в исходнике 
        values = [val.text.strip() for val in rows[2].find_all('td')]
        for key in constructor:
            constructor[key] += [values[headers[key]]]

    pd.DataFrame(constructor).to_excel('./test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

На выходе получаем вот такой excel
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужны только несколько конкретных столбцов то:

```py
    with open('test.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as html:
        soup = Soup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

    rows = soup.find_all('tr')

    headers_row: Tag
    headers_row = rows[1]

    headers = {td.text.strip(): num for num, td in enumerate(headers_row.find_all('td'))}
    constructor = {
        'Prim': [],
        'PrimRadio': []
    }

    for row in rows[2:]:
        values = [val.text.strip() for val in rows[2].find_all('td')]
        for key in constructor:
            constructor[key] += [values[headers[key]]]

    pd.DataFrame(constructor).to_excel('./test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False, encoding='cp1251')
```

> P.S. Но чисто через `pandas` как здесь уже предложили как мне кажется изящней

**UUPD**  Для большого количества строк

```py
# Время выполнения около 4х минут на 53000 tr
import re

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from progressbar import ProgressBar 
# прогресс бар для антуражу. установка pip install progressbar2

with open('test.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as html:
    f = html.read()

    iterator = re.finditer(r'<TR>.+?</TR>', f, flags=re.S)
    iter_len = len(re.findall(r'<TR>.+?</TR>', f, flags=re.S))
next(iterator)

headers_row = Soup(next(iterator).group(0), 'html.parser')

headers = {td.text.strip(): num for num, td in enumerate(headers_row.find_all('td'))}

constructor = {
    'Prim': [],
    'PrimRadio': []
}


def get_values(html_tag: str):
    soup = Soup(html_tag, 'html.parser')
    values = [val.text.strip() for val in soup.find_all('td')]
    for key in constructor:
        constructor[key] += [values[headers[key]]]


iter_count = 0
with ProgressBar(max_value=iter_len) as bar:
    while True:
        try:
            get_values(next(iterator).group(0))
            iter_count += 1
            bar.update(iter_count)
        except StopIteration:
            pd.DataFrame(constructor).to_excel('./test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False, encoding='cp1251')
            break
```

Comment: Тоже хотел сперва привести решение через `bs4`, но когда прикинул, как мапить данные на такое количество колонок, да еще чтоб и не ошибиться... В общем мне стало дико лень и решил, что `pandas` будет уместнее :)

Comment: Большое спасибо за код, он работает но только для одной строки, что делать если у меня их больше 1000? попробовал закинуть в парсер файл где 3 разных строки, он записывает 3 раза всё что в первой строке лежит .

Comment: @АндрейБурчик, Вы можете как-то показать файл с хотя-бы 10-ю тегами `tr` Просто на основании того фрагмента что вы дали в качестве примера, полностью структуру документа понять невозможно, а без этого невозможно организовать корректную обработку. Код во втором блоке смотрите он работает для всех строк после строки с заголовками

Comment: обновил ссылку, структура не особо отличается от того что было в первом примере, просто описание разное, а всё остальное тупо дублируется , я попробовал запустить код из второго блока, он записывает первую строку столько раз сколько встречает тег tr
( могу сразу сказать что в исходном файле  строк 1744706)

Comment: @Namerek, когда я на радостях запустил ваш код для полного файла, то  комп знатно озадачился и минут через 20  выкинул Memory Error

Comment: @АндрейБурчик Кстати, пока скрипт отрабатывает 1 200 000 `tr` Вам не приходило в голову, что такие объемы данных лучше не excel хранить )

Comment: @Namerek, это вынужденная мера на 1 раз, ибо та бд из которой я это достал не может нормально импортировать всё вместе

Comment: я так понял что нужно что то изменить тут values = [val.text.strip() for val in rows[2].find_all('td')], а точнее меня смущает rows[2], мб из-за этого он записывает только 3 строку?

Comment: @АндрейБурчик, Внизу добавил вариант.

Comment: @Namerek,огромное вам спасибо, за терпение и понимание, вы меня очень выручили

Comment: @АндрейБурчик, Не за что, ответ пометьте принятым

Comment: @АндрейБурчик боюсь вас разочаровать, но в excel лимит строк ~1 400 000 и вам этого может не хватить примерно на ~300 000.

Comment: @cauf `pd.DataFrame(constructor).to_csv` решает проблему

Comment: А я и не говорю, что не решает. Но задача же поставлена в импорте данных в excel. А данный формат имеет явные ограничения, в которые не вписывается массив данных автора

Comment: @cauf, спасибо за беспокойство, всё обошлось и строк вышло меньше чем я писал, я описал общее количество строк которые необходимо обработать, т.е  все строки в файле.

Answer (score 2):

Самым коротким способом будет сделать подобное через Pandas. Решение фактически занимает всего 2 строчки:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Здесь мы считываем данные из файла с html-кодом таблицы
df = pd.read_html(
    r'path/to/test.html',   # путь до файла с таблицей
    header = 1,             # номер строки с заголовками (у вас это вторая строка)
    encoding='utf-8',       # кодировка файла
)[0]  # так как функция возвращает список датафреймов, то берем первый результат

# следующая функция сохранит из полученного датафрейма 
# все строки по выбранным колонкам (Prim, PrimRadio)
# в файл с расширением xlsx
df[['Prim', 'PrimRadio']].to_excel(
    r'path/to/test.xlsx', # путь до файла xlsx
    encoding='cp1251',    # кодировка. В Windows корректно отображается cp1251
)
```

Comment: немного сократил Ваш код `pd.read_html(r'test.html', header=1, encoding='utf-8')[0][['Prim', 'PrimRadio']].to_excel(r'test.xlsx', encoding='cp1251', index=False)`

Comment: Да, так тоже можно. Но все таки для новичка подобные однострочники смотрятся монструозно. Да и комменты к ним не напишешь

Comment: спасибо что потратили своё время что бы мне помочь, но к сожалению у меня ошибку выдаёт убрал только строку с кодировкой encoding='utf-8',  ибо я руками меняю кодировку 
Ошибки:
header=1 
in read_htmldisplayed_only=displayed_only,
in _parseparser = _parser_dispatch(flav),
in _parser_dispatch raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it"),

Comment: Вам нужно установить библиотеку lxml - она понадобиться для любого парсера html. А строку с кодировкой убирать нельзя, иначе кашу получите. Нужно ставить ту, в которой на данный момент сохранен документ

Comment: поставил библиотеку lxml, потом он попросил html5lib но ошибок меньше не стало. у код который выше с кодировкой не работает, а без неё всё прекрасно, собственно поэтому и убирал ею в вашем коде, ибо ругается на неё

Comment: Ну так установите html5lib. В чем проблема?

Comment: установил всё что он хотел,не помогло

Comment: Приведите полный вывод при запуске данного скрипта. Прямо от строчки запуска до самого конца. Лучше всего это поместить вконец вопроса, либо на отдельный ресурс типа pastebin